# How to correctly copy an array element in smarty

Tags: smarty

I want to copy array element into another array element.

I have an smarty array $product: {["link"]=> "aaa" ["test"]=> 22 }

I want to have: {["link"]=> "aaa" ["test"]=> 22 **["url"]=> "aaa"** }

I tried variations of

```
{assign var=$product.url value=$product.link}
{assign var=product.url value=product.link}
{assign var='product.url' value=$product.link}
etc.
```

But this either causes errors or the variable is not being rewritten.
How to correctly copy an array element in smarty?

Answer (score 0):

```
{$product['url'] = $product['link']}
```

or

```
{$product['url'] = $product.link}
```

Comment: if I do this, then product.url works but all other vars are cleared. $product.link is empty. It's Prestashop smarty.